# How to loop through a custom post type using a shortcode and output each element in the loop using shortcodes

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, shortcode

I have a php function which loops through a custom post type and outputs a number of different elements.

For example:

1. an opening li tag
2. an img tag
3. an opening div tag
4. a title
5. a description
6. a button
7. a closing div tag
8. a closing li tag

I have attached the function to a shortcode [sc_loop]. The user enters the shortcode on a page and the loop in my function gets executed and outputs the elements without any problems.

However, I want the user to be able to format elements 4,5 and 6 individually (for example font size, color, bold, underline etc.) using the tinyMCE rich text editor.

My first thought was to assign each element it's own shortcode ([sc_title], [sc_description], [sc_button]), each outputting the relevant information from my CPT loop.

But how do I get the individual shortcodes to fire within my [sc_loop] shortcode whilst still enabling the user to format each shortcode individually?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: you definitely want parameters, but without your code, it's hard to help implement

Answer (score -1):

Probably you need to create a shortcode with parameters. You should have different parameters for font size, color, bold, underline or anything else. The user should insert a value for each of these parameters in the shortcode.

You can find what you need here
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/

It is a little tricky though because you must check the user input, because you can never be sure the user will input the proper value of a parameter.